# Increase Response time of visual studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, project

I am facing many problems with the visual studio 2013.

I have the following problems when I am working on a project:-

1. Response time is slow:- When I type something in html screen freezes for few seconds and then again starts to work. It feels like it is trying to find something. This happens in the HTML part.
2. Collapsing the blocks comes late as it takes more loading time.
3. Intellisense is not working or working late(same as what is happening to collapsing)

I am facing this problem for a single solution and other solutions work nicely.

I suspect this might be an issue with the heavy load of css files and js files or as I have 11 Projects in the same solution.

I want a solution to make the response time better.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It was because I was including external code, such as

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></xscript>
```

apparently VS does not cache this?!

The solution is

1. disable the script src (change to scrXipt)
2. edit the file
3. fix the script src
4. save it